# How to use WCF method with jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, wcf

I am testing my first WCF Service. It has only one method which equals two values given as parameters and returns the result.

It works fine when I use the Test Client provided by Visual Studio, but when I through to develop my own JS client using jQuery, I don´t know how to read data or how to call this method to obtain and show in an alert.

Here is the code:

**ImiServicio.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace primerwcf
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ImiServicio
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int getSuma(int numero1, int numero2);
    }
}
```

**miServicio.svc.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace primerwcf
{

    public class miServicio : ImiServicio
    {
        public int getSuma(int numero1, int numero2)
        {
            return numero1+numero2;
        }
    }
}
```

**webconfig**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>    
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Javascript/Jquery code**

```
$("#b1").click(function()
{
    $.ajax(
    {

         type: "GET",
         url:"http://localhost:50664/miServicio.svc",
         data:{

             numero1:2,
             numero2:6
         },
         dataType: "xml" ,
         success:function(response)
         {
             alert("ok "+response);

         },
         error:function(){

             alert("error");
         }


    });

});
```

When I simply show

```
alert(response);
```

it retuns an object XMLDocument

But when I try to use

```
$.parseXML(response);
```

It returns null.

I changed dataType to "text" in the ajax() method but I only obtain the HTML code that would be shown in the browser when I paste the address.

I tried to call the method this way, too:

```
response.getSumarResult
```

but it returns undefined.

I looked into these sources, among others:

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/544312/HowplustoplusreadplusXMLplusFileplusinplusaplusWCF

http://www.developerin.net/a/62-Code-Snippets/49-Calling-WCF-services-using-Jquery

Since most of the tutorials consulted are old, I don´t know if I have to config the webConfig file like some of this sites suggest, given that it seems I obtain the data successfully from the service.

Comment: You should get an object with your jQuery call, and you don't have to parse the `xml`. Are you able to interact with result, something like `alert(response.result);`?

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual No, when i use `alert(reponse); ` it returns object XMLDocument, but when I do `alert(response.result);` it returns undefined

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual in case it is useful, when i specify no dataType and I do `alert(response);` , then it returns ALL the HTML document that would be shown when I give the service address on browser (instructions to create a client, and so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tests and efforts, I managed to solve it. I will post here what I´ve done for other people with the same problem.

Notice **I am using VS 2017:**

-First of all, I deleted both ImiServicio.cs and miServicio.svc.cs

-Select current project/ add new element and then include a new WCF Service with AJAX enabled. You won´t need to create the interface this way.

-On new WCF, I added this code to the getSuma() method:

```
**[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]**
    public int getSuma(int numero1, int numero2)
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType =  "text/xml";
            return numero1 + numero2;
        }
```

The line "WebOperationContext..." in the body of the method seems to be not mandatory, but VS suggested to include it so I did.

-Now, we go to the jQuery code and we change these line:

```
url:"http://localhost:50664/miServicio.svc"
```

Notice I am not calling the method on the old code, so do this:

```
url:"http://localhost:50664/miServicio.svc/getSuma"
```

-Next, on success function, replace this:

```
alert("ok "+ response);
```

With this:

```
/*use the text() jQuery method to obtain the value returned by the method*/
alert("ok "+$(response).text());
```

IMPORTANT: I still don´t know how to enable CORS by code so I had to use a [firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/) to avoid this problem, for the moment. If you don´t enable, you will get error despite response is OK (status 200).

Comment: You are basically parsing the `XMLDocument` with jquery here (on the `$(response).text()` part). The rest of the answer is really not needed. This will work for simple primitive return values... if you return any class or structure with serialized properties, you'll have to parse those too. I'd recommend switching to JSON responses if you don't *need* XML and your client will always be javascript, since it'll be already parsed for you (JSON is native to modern javascript, and you'll be able to use the response value directly)